# Error with xpath on automation selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have this HTML code on UI

```
<a href="javascript: void edit('edit_total_amt')" title="Override total tax amount" onmouseover="status='Override total tax amount'; return true">0.00</a>
```

and i have to select the WebElement identified by the tag option with text Auto. I try some solution like:

```
public void clickOnItemTax () {
        By tag = By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Override total tax percent')]"); 
        //By tag = By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Total Tax')]");
        //By tag = By.name("TotalTaxPercent");
        this.sleep(3);
        if (this.waitForExistence(tag, 60)) {
            WebElement domLink = linkGet(tag);
            domLink.click();
        } else {
            JLog.fail("Attempting to click on item tax but not found :" + tag );
        }
}
```

Error i getting was :

FAIL: Attempting to click on item tax but not found :By.xpath: //a[contains(@title,'Override total tax percent')]

Kindly advise , thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

judging by your html sample you are providing the wrong selector in your xpath, should be:

```
By tag = By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Override total tax amount')]");
```

Comment: the xpath you given exactly the same as i put , what's the different?

Comment: no its not, look again. You have By tag = "Override total tax percent" whereas your title attribute has "'Override total tax amount"

Comment: Sorry my mistake , of the percent and amount.

Comment: may i know is that possible i use xpath by onmouseover=status ?

Comment: not sure to be honest. Have never tried it, trial and error is your best bet.